# I can't reach the download speed result of speedtest

Tags: windows-8, internet-speed, speedtest

I'm from the Philippines. I have a PLDT connection. My download speed at speedtest goes up to 1183kB/s but my download speed only reaches 300kB/s. Is there something wrong with my internet connection? How can I reach my speedtest download speed?

Comment: What download speed are you paying for?

Comment: When performing your speedtest are you using the nearest supplied test site or are you testing it with a server closer to where your download is coming from? SpeedTest servers are frequently located at your ISPs Central Office so those tests are not accurate when it comes to actual download speeds which you experience.

Comment: Sometimes you can achieve better speed by using downloaders (such as Download Master, Reget). They use another ways for downloading to get maximum of your internet.

Comment: kBp/s or kbp/s ? There's difference between them: B/s is Bytes/sec and b/s is bits/sec.

Comment: The servers that you connect to can throttle (or are themselves limited in the) speed at which data can be downloaded.

Comment: Jason Aller: My internet connection is up to 1.5mbps.

Comment: abhishekkanojia: kBps small k big letter B

Answer (score 3):

There are a great deal of things that go into transfer speeds.  Speedtest and similar websites use sites that are close to you, in order to show you the best possible result.  Your ISP, or any other intermediate ISP could be constraining/limiting the maximum transfer rates for your data transfer.  It could also be the *upload* speed from the remote host that is limiting the connections transfer speed.  It could be a lot of other things.

It takes significant technical skill with the technology, using various tools, to work out where the problem is.  You need to be able to use tools like netstat, ping, pingplotter, and traceroute/tracert, and understand networking topology.

For us to help you more, you need to provide latency results from ping, and traceroute transcripts to workout where your problem lies.

Comment: Mr.David, How can i provide the latency results and traceroute transcripts?

Comment: You need to learn how to use the commandline, and then learn how to use  netstat, ping, pingplotter, and traceroute/tracert, and understand networking topology.  Google might be a good start.

Comment: Thank you Mr. David. I would like to ask 1 last question. If I am were able to learn all this and I discovered that my ISP is the one constraining and limiting my transfer rate, Will i be able to remove that limit?

Comment: Probably not, generally your only option is to change ISP's, or upgrade your service with them.